# Как сделать связи между 3-мя моделями (таблицами)?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, laravel, postgresql, relationship

Есть 3 таблицы и соответственно 3 сущности:

1. companies [id, name ...]
2. services [id, service]
3. prices [id, currency, price]

Мне нужно вывести на странице, условно, `company 1` все её услуги (`services`) и цены (`prices`) каждой услуги. Я понимаю, что тут связь многие ко многим, но не понимаю, как вывести на страницу компании услуги и цены на неё в следующем виде:

- Услуга 1 - 1200 ₽
- Услуга 2 - 2300 ₽
- Услуга 3 - 900 ₽

при этом чтобы цены и услуги не перепутались? Если сделать связь между `company -> services` и `company -> prices` можно, то как сделать связь между `service -> price`, чтобы каждая цена соответствовала своей услуге? У каждой компании может быть много услуг и цен. Также одна услуга может быть и у одной компании и у другой, но цены на одну и ту же услугу могут различаться. Как правильно связать эти 3 таблицы?

Comment: Хранить company_id в price помимо service_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Храните цену в промежуточной таблице **company_service**. Будет 3 колонки: `company_id`, `service_id`, `price`.
Добавьте отношение для модели **Company**

```
public function services()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class)->withPivot('price');
}
```

Блок в документации [Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)